# Applying same function over a list of variables

Tags: functions, import, automation

I currently have a list of variables in a column in excel, I would like to perform some analysis for each of those variables.

```
  dataset = Dataset[Import["filename.xlsx"]];
  dataset1 = dataset[1, All, 1];
```

Could anyone please help me with inputting each variable in each row of the column into unique variables such that i could run functions for each of those variable?

For example,
the excel file looks like this:

```
         A
         B
         C
         D
         E
```

And i would like to perform functions in Mathematica for each of those variables.
If i wanted to add 2 to each of those variables and export out to another excel that says:

```
        A+2
        B+2
        C+2
        D+2
        E+2
```

What should i do?

Comment: Have you seen `Map`? You might also consider using some of the unique methods that can be done with the `Dataset`. It is a trivial task, and the examples found on the respective reference pages/documentation will give you a good idea of how to do what you want.

Comment: `Map` is a better option. Or you can simply use `data2=Table[{dataset1[[i]],dataset1[[i]]+2},{i,1,Length[dataset1]}];` and then `Export` `data2`.